# Instanced objects ignored when baking normals

Tags: baking, normal-map, instances

So I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lA9bw9boQ4) on youtube on how to make tileable textures and I've tried making one on my own.

When I tried baking I realised that the instanced objects where ignored in the process. Here you can see what my High Poly mesh looks like from the top.

[image]

and here you can see what my normal map ended up looking like

[image]

As you can see, the instanced objects are nowhere to be found on the normal map. I've already asked under the video for an alternate way until it gets fixed but I wonder if someone here has an idea on how to actually fix that ?

Comment: I JUST ran into this exact same problem, and have found no answers. i didn't want to post the same question as a new one.

Comment: I've seen the video rapidly. I don't think he's backing the dupli from where the bake is done. Though I don't see where this setup leads to (if not). But the 3D view render with the matcap could do what you want.

Comment: Just do a research for "make duplicates real" or something like that in the blender tool search bar once you are happy with the results and it will bake